# Adding close link on a bootstrap modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a pop up window form and I used bootstrap modal to make it work. Here's the id and class of the window.

```
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">

<a href="#" class="close-modal" id="close-modal">Close</a>

<div class="modal-header">
<p>Hello there!</p>
</div>


<div class="modal-body">
<!--email form-->
</div>

</div>
```

I use this jquery code to make it work. But still doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').hide(); //hides the modal div to be displayed later
    $('#close-modal').on('click', function(){ 
        $('#myModal, #close-modal').toggle();
        $('#myModal').modal();
    });

    $('#close-modal').on('click', function(){ 
        $('#myModal').modal.close();
        $('#myModal, #close-modal').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have two different `click` handler for `$('#close-modal')`?

Comment: i'm just trying which of these two are working. @Felix

Comment: @PorkChop Did you include the jQuery.js before Bootstrap.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').hide(); //hides the modal div to be displayed later

    $(document).on('click', '#close-modal' , function(){ 
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, his modal has id="myModal", so he can target using $('#myModal')

Comment: i tried to change it to "#myModal" but still doesnt work @flauntster

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myModal').hide(); //hides the modal div to be displayed later
        $('#close-modal').on('click', function(){ 
           //Hide model with animation->$("#myModal").animate({opacity:'hide'}, 400);
            $("#myModal").hide();
        });  
    });
</script>
```

Above code will hide modal popup on close link click Check working example for more details.http://jsfiddle.net/NB3JT/light/